# Eventlog and Windows-event-log merge

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

It seems to me that [eventlog](/questions/tagged/eventlog) (~300 questions) and [windows-event-log](/questions/tagged/windows-event-log) (~60 questions) refer to the same thing.  I kind of like [windows-event-log](/questions/tagged/windows-event-log) as being more descriptive, but [eventlog](/questions/tagged/eventlog) seems to be winning.  Shall we synonym/merge, and if so in which direction?

Comment: I'd say synonimze and merge with `windows-event-log` as the master.  Keeps people from needing to change their habits, while introducing new users to the better tag.

Comment: Looks like we've been overruled :-).  Well, we're still much better off than where we started.

Comment: The merge I chose avoids the problem of a specific technology (Windows) co-opting a general term (event log). We currently have this problem with [tag:activity], a general term with multiple meanings that was co-opted for [tag:android].

Comment: A good point, though it seems all of the event-log questions are windows related.  Perhaps we should have mass-retagged to windows-event-log and left event-log empty?  Or is the event-log tag useful across different platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed: 
[windows-event-log](/questions/tagged/windows-event-log) --> [event-log](/questions/tagged/event-log) and 
[eventlog](/questions/tagged/eventlog) --> [event-log](/questions/tagged/event-log)